# mLab Connect Error: Database name cannot have reserved characters for mongodb://

Tags: mongodb, mlab

I'm encountering a mongoDB connect error while running mLab commands to connect through mongo shell. Running under Windows git bash terminal with mLab command below. I'm not using any reserved characters for database name, basically just a lowercase string. Any idea?

To connect using the mongo shell:

```
mongo ds237967.mlab.com:37967/<database> -u <dbuser> -p <dbpassword>





connecting to: mongodb://<database>:27017/ds237967.mlab.com%3A37967
2018-01-01T00:20:45.371-0800 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: Database name cannot have reserved characters for mongodb:// URL: mongodb://<databasename>:27017/ds237967.mlab.com%3A37967 :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:240:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Comment: This URL that the shell is trying to connect to `mongodb://<database>:27017/ds237967.mlab.com%3A37967` is completely malformed. Did you change it when redacting the database name? It should be just `ds237967.mlab.com:37967/<database>`.

Comment: The error and the command in your question don't seem to match. This is the kind of error you would get if you were running a command like this: `mongo <database>:27017/ds237967.mlab.com:37967 -u <dbuser> -p <dbpassword>`. Are you editing the hostname from the mLab portal in any way?

Comment: I suspect the problem is with the malformed URL, which I did not change it at all. Only command I ran was "mongo ds237967.mlab.com:37967/<database> -u <dbuser> -p <dbpassword>" and the malformed URL is generated automatically.

Comment: I created the database in mLab portal with the name <database> and did not edit the hostname after that. I copied that command directly from mLab portal.

Comment: Okay... I think you should email support@mlab.com - we may be able to help you troubleshoot in more detail over email.

Comment: Looks like that command is being automatically URL encoded and therefore  not being recognized correctly.

Answer (score 4):

instead of using

```
mongo ds237967.mlab.com:37967/<database> -u <dbuser> -p <dbpassword>
```

try

```
mongo --port 37967 --host ds237967.mlab.com <database> -u <dbuser> -p <dbpassword>
```

it should work as it worked for me. Let me know if it doesnt

Answer (score 1):

You should remove "<>" characters while writing your database  name etc.

Here is an example:

```
mongo ds237967.mlab.com:37967/databaseName -u dbUser -p dbpassword
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've run into this bug:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-31437

Where the hostname and database in the URL get transposed.

If this is the case, the workaround for your current version of Mongo is to specify the port and hostname using the --port and --host arguments as described in the answer by hasysf.

Otherwise, consider upgrading to a version where this is fixed (either v3.4.12 or v3.6).

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace  with the name of the database that connections will use by default:

```
mongo "mongodb+srv://sandbox.5xx8l.mongodb.net/<dbname>" --username <dbuser> --password<dbpassword>
```

You can also remove database from the code. Below code should work fine:

```
mongo ds237967.mlab.com:37967 -u <dbuser> -p <dbpassword>
```